# javascript - arguments.callee.toString() and arguments.callee.name does not return function name

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to get the name of the currently running function. From what I've read, this should be possible using:

```
(arguments.callee.toString()).match(/function\s+(\[^\s\(]+)/)
```

However, when I run this in Firefox and Safari (latest versions on Mac) the name is not returned.

console.log( arguments.callee ) returns the source of the function, but not the assigned name. arguments.callee.name returns an empty string.

My sample code is as follows:

```
var testobj = {
    testfunc: function(){
        console.log( (arguments.callee.toString()).match(/function\s+(\[^\s\(]+)/) );
    }
}
testobj.testfunc();
```

Comment: Can I ask, why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: Yah. So I'm working on a pet project involving function chaining. I have about 50 different functions that all run the same code, except that a particular variable in them is defined as the same name of the function.

I want to reduce all of the duplication to a single function that detects the name of the calling function and uses that name as the variable that's currently hard coded.

With this method, I can define all of my functions in a single line.

Comment: `toString()` ing functions like this (aka function "decompilation") has its warts. See http://perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions/, http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-built-in-host-methods/, http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/show.dml/1665828 and http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2007/07/07/prototype-findorstore-considered-harmful

Comment: I have to say I'm pretty disappointed by the utterly piss poor answers to this question, none of them seem like they were tested whatsoever

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical arguments.callee hacks don't work here because what you've done is assigned an anonymous function as the value for the object's 'testfunc' key.  In this case the hacking even gets worse, but it can be done, as follows:

```
var testobj = {
    testfunc: function(){
      for (var attr in testobj) {
              if (testobj[attr] == arguments.callee.toString()) {
                  alert(attr);
                  break;
                }
            }
    }
}
testobj.testfunc();
```

Answer (score 11):

You declared an anonymous function with

```
function(){
```

You should declare it as

```
function testfunc(){
```

to get the name printed.

Comment: Be aware that named function expressions (which is what you're suggesting) behave oddly in IE. See http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/

Comment: To clarify: in the case of the object style above that would be `{ testfunc: function testfunc() { ...`. This is also nice to do when debugging things in the browser, helps the debugger help you see which function you have problems in.

Comment: According to the Wayback Machine, the link in @TimDown 's comment redirects to http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ before the domain name expired

Answer (score 3):

On firefox 3.5, Safari 5, and Chrome 6.0 you can use:

```
function myFunctionName() {
 alert("Name is " + arguments.callee.name );
}

myFunctionName();
```

You can also get the function that called the current one using arguments.callee.caller.

Answer (score 2):

```
/function\s+(\[^\s\(]+)/
```

What's with the backslash before `[`? I don't think you want a literal square bracket here. Without that it should work.

Although I'd **strongly** recommend against anything to do with sniffing function name or especially sniffing caller function. Almost anything you might do using these hideous hacks will be better done using some combination of closures and lookups.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a much cleaner and elegant solution to all this. Assuming the function is a member of some higher-level object—and that's always going to be the case, even if the function's owner is "window" or some other global object, we can access the global object via the **this** keyword, we can access the function itself via **arguments.callee** and we can access all the parent's object (function) names via **for (var o in this)**, so you should be able to get the desired information fairly easily as...

```
returnMyName = function() {
  for (var o in this) {
    if (arguments.callee===this[o]) return o;
  }
};
```

That should be robust and avoid any weird IE browser behaviors accessing named functions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function.prototype.getName = function(fn) {
    if(Function.name || Function.prototype.name) return this.name;
    return this.toString().match(/^function\s+(\w+)\s*\(/)[1];
};
```

Comment: Please add a description of the answer!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the function doesn't have a name. The function name is what you put in-between `function` and the arguments list `(...)`. Here's how to get a function's name (don't use the `name` property, as it can be changed):

```
var fName = arguments.callee.toString(0).match(
  /^function\s*(?:\s+([\w\$]*))?\s*\(/
);
fName = (fName ? fName[1] : "");
```

Comment: "don't use the name property, as it can be changed" - well, the toString() method can be changed as well...

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you simply log the function object, like so:

```
console.log(arguments.callee)
```

or

```
console.debug(arguments.callee)
```

that you simply get the function name in the console log with some options.