# Getting the names of executing functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the names of all the javascript function executed on a page?

something like

```
console.info(functionname)
```

As I am trying to fix some bugs on a customer's page and all javascript function are sepreaded all over the website withing PHP files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the current function can be obtained via [`arguments.callee.name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935521/javascript-arguments-callee-tostring-and-arguments-callee-name-does-not-retu/3977092#3977092). The name of any function is available in the `name` property of the funciton reference.

Use [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/console.trace) to print the current stack trace. That does not only print the current function name, but also the previous ones.

If you want to get a string, containing the stack, have a look at [How to get result of console.trace() as string in javascript with chrome or firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715571/how-to-get-result-of-console-trace-as-string-in-javascript-with-chrome-or-fire).